# Program stops working on return of custom object from function

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to return the object `LorentzBoostedVector` of the class `FourVector` from this function, which is a member of `FourVector`. The class is derived from a `Vector` general class, and contains a pointer to an array of size 4 containing data called `elementData`.  Here I call the default constructor of `FourVector` and then set it's `elementData` components using the formulae in the code. I then try to return the object by value.

The code works correctly and creates the `FourVector` (I have checked this) but the program stops working when I try to return the `LorentzBoostedVector`. Any idea why this might be? I have a feeling it is something to do with destructors being called before the object is returned but I don't know how to fix this.

```
    FourVector LorentzBoost(ThreeVector& betaVector) {
    double gamma = betaVector.gamma();
    FourVector LorentzBoostedVector;
    ThreeVector r(elementData[1], elementData[2], elementData[3]);
    LorentzBoostedVector[0] = gamma*(elementData[0] - betaVector.dotProduct(r));
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        LorentzBoostedVector[i] = r[i-1] + (((gamma - 1)*betaVector.dotProduct(r) / betaVector.dotProduct(betaVector)) - gamma*elementData[0])*betaVector[i - 1];
    }
    return LorentzBoostedVector;
}
```

The constructors and destructors of the `FourVector` class are

```
    //default constructor for FourVector
FourVector() {
    delete[] elementData;
    numberOfDimensions = 4;
    elementData = new double[numberOfDimensions];
}
    //parameterised constructor for FourVector
FourVector(double ct, double x, double y, double z) {
    delete[] elementData;
    numberOfDimensions = 4;
    elementData = new double[4];
    elementData[0] = ct; elementData[1] = x;elementData[2] = y;elementData[3] = 1;
}
~FourVector() {
    cout << "Four Vector Destructor Called" << endl;
    delete[] elementData;
}
```

Comment: Most probably you violated the rule of 3/5, but without [mcve] it is impossible to say more

Comment: Apologies, I'll try to write a better example now

Comment: Just show all constructors and destructor of `FourVector` first, I bet it would be enough.

Comment: @Slava I have edited the question to add them

Comment: Check that you return vector NOT by reference.

Comment: I have resolved the problem. The `Vector` class from which `FourVector` inherits contained a destructor that deleted the elementData. Both destructors were called the program was trying to delete the elementData array twice. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: You should either write a copy constructor that does a deep copy of the data, or make your class non copyable, or use a standard class for handling your array such as std::vector or std::array.

Comment: You have not, you have much more problems in your code.

Comment: What sort of problems?

Comment: You should not call delete in ctor, you are missing copy and maybe move ctor, you are violating rule of 3 indeed. And most probably much more, but this is as match as I can say based on what you provided.

Comment: Ah okay, I will fix that now. Thank you